# Error handling for a doFinally block in apache camel

Tags: error-handling, apache-camel

I have a camel rest api which has a doTry, doCatch and doFinally blocks. I have to handle error cases that come in the doFinally block as well. When using doTry .. doCatch .. doFinally, the regular Camel error handler does not apply so how to handle error cases in doFinally block. I have a `to` statement in the doFinally block which needs error handling and an if condition inside a processor in the doFinally block which needs error handling. The code is like so ->

```
.post("send-req")
  .route()
  .doTry()
    // Some Code
  .doCatch()
   //Some Code 
  .doFinally()
     // Need  error handling for the to statement below
    .to()
    .process(new Processor(){
       @Override
       public void process(Exchange exchange){
           //Need  error handling for the if statement 
          if(condition)
             throw new BadRequestException();
      }
    })
  .endRest();
```

I tried doing route-specific error handling  like so ->

```
.post("send-req")
  .route()
  .doTry()
    // Some Code
  .doCatch()
   //Some Code 
  .doFinally()
     // Need  error handling for the to statement below
    .to()
      .onException(SalesforceException.class)
         .handled(true)
         .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, new ValueBuilder(new SimpleExpression("${exception.statusCode}")))
         .transform(exceptionMessage())
         .end()
    .process(new Processor(){
       @Override
       public void process(Exchange exchange){
          //Need  error handling for the if statement 
          if(condition)
             throw new BadRequestException();
       }
    })
    .onException(BadRequestException.class)
       .handled(true)
       .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(400))
       .transform(exceptionMessage())
       .end()                                       
  .endRest();
```

But this gives an error `The output must be added as top-level on the route. Try moving OnException[[org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.SalesforceException] -> []] to the top of route`. How should a case like this be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Move the onException block outside the route.

It should be something like this:

```
onException(SalesforceException.class)
     .handled(true)
     .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, new ValueBuilder(new SimpleExpression("${exception.statusCode}")))
     .transform(exceptionMessage());

onException(BadRequestException.class)
   .handled(true)
   .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(400))
   .transform(exceptionMessage());

rest("/")
.post("send-req")
  .route()
  .someCodeThatThrowsSalesForceException
  .someCodeThatThrowsBadRequestException                         
  .endRest();
```

Comment: When using doTry .. doCatch .. doFinally, the regular Camel error handler does not apply  so it wont detect those onException clauses which are outside the route. I already tried this

Comment: That is because you are already catching the exceptions. You can get rid of the try catch stuff altogether. I have edited my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Actually my try block is executing something if that fails then I have to execute the catch block and then doFinally is executed so I can't remove that. The data needed in the doFinally block is either coming from the doTry if there is no error else it is coming from doCatch. Is there some other way to do this. I am basically execute a ```to``` statement in  a try block and setting headers based on the response of the ```to``` statement, if there is an error I am setting some headers in the catch block and then finally executing the doFinally block which also needs error handling.

Comment: What exception does your doCatch handle?

Comment: In my doTry block, I am fetching a file from s3, if that file doesn't exist(S3Exception) then doCatch is executed

Comment: Okay, so still, get rid of the try catch, and add another onException block for S3Exception. If you need to continue with your route after the exception add `continued(true)` in your onException block

Comment: But if that file is not there it will just raise an exception and won't execute the code after that right? So whatever is there in the doFinally won't get executed

Comment: That's what I said. If you need to continue with your route after the exception, add `continued(true)`

Comment: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html#ExceptionClause-HandleandContinueExceptions